# Edit text file using batch file

Tags: batch-file, replace, line

I've searched a thousand of example and tried, but none of them actually works for me. My requirement is pretty straight forward, I have a file - config.txt, it has one of lines:

sqlServer=localhost

I'm trying to update this line to:

sqlServer=myMachine\sql2012

I looked examples online, some of them are just working with set variables, or some are not replacing but inserting. There are some examples are writing into a new file, but the new file has line number in front of each line. I don't find a useful instruction how to write batch scripts, and none of the update file batch scripts works for me.

It will be very helpful if you leave some comments.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDITED - to adapt to comments

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "config=.\config.txt"
    set "dbServer=localhost\sql2012"

    for /f "tokens=*" %%l in ('type "%config%"^&cd.^>"%config%"'
    ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims== " %%a in ("%%~l"
    ) do if /i "%%~a"=="sqlServer" (
        >>"%config%" echo(sqlServer=%dbServer%
    ) else (
        >>"%config%" echo(%%l
    )

    type "%config%"

    endlocal
```

Input file is read line by line (`for /f %%l`), then each line is split (`for /f %%a`) and if the first token in the line is "sqlserver" then the line is replaced, else the original line is sent to file.

The command used to retrieve the information in the first `for` loop includes an `cd.>"%config%"` that will remove the contents of the file, so the final resulting lines (that have been read in memory by the `for` command before removing them) are sent directly to the same file.

Comment: what if I want to pass parameter to assign the sqlServer value?
I updated to:
set dbServer=localhost\sql2012
..............

SET SqlServer=%dbServer%

but it's not working

Comment: @user3621995, Not sure about the code in your comment. See updated answer. Is this what you were trying?

Comment: It actually works, thanks for the reply. The problem before has something to do with the file coding, for "set", it adds some special characters before it, so it's not recognized as a command. I created another batch file, and copied everything and it worked. 
Is this scripts only search for the token, meaning the start string  separated by space? I have another example <add key="DatabaseServer" value="localhost"/>, I need to replace "localhost" to %dbServer%, but the scripts is not working, I think it cannot find out "DatabaseServer" because it's in the middle of a token, right?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
FINDSTR /I /V /B "sqlServer=" config.txt > config.new
ECHO sqlServer=myMachine\sql2012 >> config.new
DEL config.txt
REN config.new config.txt
```

The `FINDSTR` will remove all lines that start with `sqlServer=` and create a new file called `newfile`.

The `ECHO` will add a line at the end with `sqlServer=MyMachine\sql2012`.

The last two lines delete your existing `config.txt` and replace it with the output of the first two lines.

Comment: That looks correct, except you should us a /q for no prompt del: `del /q config.txt`

Comment: hi Mark, the scripts removes all other lines as well, "sqlServer= "is one of the line, and there are other parameters i don't want to change, do you know how can keep those?

Comment: Change the last part of the very first line of my script so it exactly matches the line you want to remove, i.e. FINDSTR /V /B "sqlServer=localhost" Failing that, edit your question and show how your file looks.