# Edit an acf file with batch file or ini file

Tags: batch-file

So I need to edit an `acf`  file, which contain

"Language" "English"

And I just need to change the language. How will I do that?

Comment: It looks like you need a simple or regular expression find and replace. So use one of the solutions posted on: [How can you find and replace text in a file using the Windows command-line environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/)

Comment: Please always make an effort and show that effort prior to posting a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is in this thread.

> [Batch / Find And Edit Lines in TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file)

In short `Batch` or `Commands` in windows does not support editing a file programmatically, So, create a vb script like given in the linked post and if you have to execute a batch then add the command which runs the vbs file in a batch file and execute it.

Comment: I actually found it here but it can only write at the end of the text how can I edit a line with this code?                                                                http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574631/edit-text-file-using-batch-file] `FINDSTR /I /V /B "sqlServer=" config.txt > config.new
ECHO sqlServer=myMachine\sql2012 >> config.new
DEL config.txt
REN config.new config.txt`